# Python ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,)(2,)

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert a couple of matrixes into a mathematical equation but this error shows.

```
import numpy as np

def survivalTemperature(M,g):

    if any(M>500) or any(M<50) or any(g<0.04) or any(g>0.45):
        T='RangeError'
        
    else:
        T=np.matmul(36-(((0.09*M-12)*(g+0.95))/(27.8*g)))

    return T
print(survivalTemperature(np.array([50,200,300]),np.array([0.20,0.14])))
```

Error below:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)

I tried using `np.matmul` but it didn't help.

Comment: Which two matrices did you want to multiply? You need to pass each as a separate argument to `matmul`. I see that you are trying to only pass one argument to `matmul`, this cannot work.

Comment: i might have misunderstoof how matmul works but i tried to put the to matrixes in the print function into the t funktion ^^